# Custom Expo Push Notification Icon Not Displaying On Android Device(s)

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo, android-push-notification

I have been able to successfully configure expo push notifications for my app (title and message appears), but I cannot for the life of me change the default expo icon (upside down V). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGGJY.png) is what's currently being displayed. I am testing on a Redmi Note 5 and a Samsung Galaxy s5 and on both devices the push notification icon seems to just not respect the icon configuration I've set according to the official documentation.

The notifications are being sent from the `exponent_server_sdk` library in Python. I am starting my devlopment expo app with `expo start` in a command line terminal and connecting from my physical device(s) from the expo app via QR code.

Things I've tried:

1. Configuring the push notification icon in my app.json as documented in the official instructions:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "BaseApp",
    "slug": "BaseApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./Image/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./Image/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./Image/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
      ]
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./Image/pleasework.png",
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./Image/pleasework.png",
      "color": "#7f2ee1",
      "androidMode": "default",
      "androidCollapsedTitle": "Updates from Colab.notes",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./Image/pleasework.png"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Resized the image to a 96x96 transparent white background image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6b94.png)
3. Cleared the expo app cache on both devices to no avail
4. Sent the local path to the image from the server as follows:

```
from exponent_server_sdk import (
    DeviceNotRegisteredError,
    PushClient,
    PushMessage,
    PushServerError,
    PushTicketError
)

@staticmethod
    def send_push_message(token, message):
        """
        Summary:
            Send a push notification to the target device.

        Args:
            token (str): Unique identifier of the phone device.
            message (str): Text to send to the target phone device.
        """
        data = {'icon': PATH_TO_APP_ICON} #Evaluates to ./Image/pleasework.png
        try:
            response = PushClient().publish(
                PushMessage(to=token,
                            title=PushNotification.TITLE,
                            body=message,
                            data=data))
```

5. Attempted to resize the images down to 72x72 pixels and up to 200x200 pixels, neither of which lead to a fruitful result.
6. Ensured that my `./Image/pleasework.png` file is in fact a valid path relative to the root directory of my project.
7. Attempted to convert an instance of my `pleasework.png` file to a base64 encoding and sent it via push notification to my app client in hopes that it may display.

I have not tested on an apple device as I currently don't have access to one. What else is left to do? I've done everything right but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your app through Expo Go, the icon is Expo icon. If you want to see your own icon you have to install the app as an standalone app ( creating it with EAS BUILD). The icon will be your own.

Answer (score 0):

First Step: Install expo-notifications

```
npx expo install expo-notifications
```

To set the icon and color properties for Android devices, you’ll need to configure the app.json file. On the other hand, iOS devices will detect the icon and background color automatically.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./src/assets/notification-icon.png",
          "color": "#082849",
          "sounds": [
            "./local/assets/notification-sound.wav",
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```